# how to open a new tab with this line (javascript?)?

Tags: javascript, tabs

how to open a new tab (in background if possible) with this line (javascript)?
 what can i add to this line to achive it open in backgound??

this is

```
javascript:Qr=document.getSelection(); \
if(!Qr){void(Qr=prompt('Diccionario%20de%20la%20Real%20Academia%20 \
Espa%C3%83%C2%B1ola.%20Vig%C3%83%C2%A9sima%20segunda%20edici%C3%83 \
%C2%B3n.%20Teclee%20la%20palabra%20que%20desea%20consultar:',''))} \
if(Qr) \
  location.href='http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual? \
  TIPO_HTML=2&TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA='+escape(Qr)+'%20'
```

There is no line break in above statement. Line-breaks are added for clarity of reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`open` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open).